# How do I write a custom validation method with parameters for my ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my model I have:

```
validate :my_custom_validation

def my_custom_validation
 errors.add_to_base("error message") if condition.exists?
end
```

I would like to add some parameters to mycustomer vaildation like so:

```
validate :my_custom_validation, :parameter1 => x, :parameter2 => y
```

How do I write the mycustomvalidation function to account for parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Validators usualy have an array parameter indicating, first, the fields to validate and lastly (if it exists) a hash with the options. In your example:

```
:my_custom_validation, parameter1: x, parameter2: y
```

:my_custom_validation would be a field name, while parameter1: x, parameter2: y would be a hash:

```
{ parameter1: x, parameter2: y}
```

Therefore, you'd do something like:

```
def my_custom_validation(*attr)
    options = attr.pop if attr.last.is_a? Hash
    # do something with options
    errors.add_to_base("error message") if condition.exists?

end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do something like this:

```
def validate
  errors.add('That particular field', 'can not be the value you presented') if !self.field_to_check.blank? && self.field_to_check == 'I AM COOL'
end
```

No need to call reference it, as I believe the validate method is processed (if it exists) after any validates_uniqueness_of -like validations.

Added: More information in the Rails API docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use a [Ruby lambda](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-function-ruby/) to help with method based validation of your model attributes (x, y) like below:

```
validate -> { my_custom_validation(parameter1: x, parameter2: y) }
```