# Pass field name as parameter to custom validation method Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, web

I have a custom validation method:

```
def my_custom_validation
  errors.add(specific_field, "error message") if specific_field.delete_if { |i| i.blank? }.blank?
end
```

The goal is to disallow parameters which contains `[""]` pass through validation, but I need to call this method like:

```
validate :my_custom_validation #and somehow pass here my field names
```

For example:

```
 validate :my_custom_validation(:industry)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you need to validate multiple attributes this way I would recommend a custom validator like so:

```
class EmptyArrayValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "cannot be emtpy") if value.delete_if(&:blank?).empty?
  end
end
```

Then validate as

```
validates :industry, empty_array: true
validates :your_other_attribute, empty_array: true
```

Or if you don't want to specifically create a class because it is only needed for 1 model you could include this in the model itself

```
validates_each :industry, :your_other_attribute, :and_one_more do |record, attr, value|
  record.errors.add(attr, "cannot be emtpy") if value.delete_if(&:blank?).empty?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep the method based validation you can use a [Ruby lambda](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-function-ruby/) like below:

```
validate -> { my_custom_validation(some_model_field) }
```

[See similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72746111/4848156)