# Validation similar to attr_readonly, but ignoring blank attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make it so that columns can be filled and updated only if they are blank. Similar to `attr_readonly` but permitting updates if the attribute is empty.

Here's my sad attempt, it fails because `before_update` tries to call `attr_readonly` on the instance.

```
before_update :check_attrs

def check_attrs
  if column_1.present?
    attr_readonly :column_1
  elsif column_2.present?
    attr_readonly :column_2
  elsif column_3.present?
    attr_readonly :column_3
  elsif column_4.present?
    attr_readonly :column_4
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume we are talking about a 'model' class that extends `ActiveRecord::Base`…

My idea is to use validations to enforce the rule: cannot set a value unless the original value was blank.

Though a different question, this helped: [Pass field name as parameter to custom validation method Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685746/pass-field-name-as-parameter-to-custom-validation-method-rails-4)

API doc for [validates_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_each):

```
validates_each :column_1, :column_2, :column_3, :column_4 do |record, attr, value|
  attr_was_present = record.changed_attributes[attr].present?
  record.errors.add(attr, 'can only change if blank') if attr_was_present
end
```

PS: that can be a one-liner, I've added a local variables to (hopefully) add a bit of clarity.

What this will do is add a 'can only change if blank' error to the list of errors of any attribute where an attempt is made to change it. The `save` will then fail and the database record will not change.

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. It causes some strange behavior where on the edit page, after submission it thinks the instance has that column filled, but the update doesn't persist and the `else` block of `if`/`else` `@instance.update` gets executed. I'll look deeper into `validates_each` and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Yes that is expected behaviour on save for a model with validation errors. It raises the question of what you would like to happen if the value changes? Show an error on the field (what I had)? Raise an exception? Quietly reset the value back to it's old value?

Comment: Oh bugger! I had the 'attr_was_blank' logic backwards. That could well be the source of the confusion. I'll update my answer now.

Comment: Works great. Thanks for following up!

Comment: I implemented the solution and it was failing at line `record.changed_attributes[attr].present?` because changed_attributes is not a Hash with indifferent access.  I had to convert attr to string.  Worked like charm.  Thanks.